# Qual a diferença entre document.getElementById e "elemento ID"?

Tags: javascript, html5

Fiquei curioso ao descobrir que é possível recuperar um elemento HTML utilizando seu ID como uma variável JavaScript.

Me surgiu então a questão: qual a diferença entre `document.getElementById` e `elementoID` e de quais modos devem ser utilizados/quais situações?

Segue um breve exemplo do que estou dizendo:

```js
console.log(divExemplo);
//Mesma coisa!
console.log(document.getElementById('divExemplo'));
```

```html
<div id="divExemplo"></div>
```